# ajax php java script integration not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a html page through which I am sending data to PHP through ajax but the code is not working.
**HTML**

```
<form name='tip' method='post' action=''>
        Tip somebody: <input name="tip_email" id=tip_email type="text" size="30"  />
        <input type="submit"   value="Skicka Tips" />
        <input type="hidden" id="ad_id" name="ad_id" />
</form>
<script>
        $('#submit').click(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                        url: insertdata.php,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                                tip_email: $('#tip_email'),
                                ad_id: $('#ad_id')
                        },
                        success: function(res) {
                                if (res == 'successful') {
                                        alert("successful");
                                } else {
                                        alert("failed");
                                }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                                $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                        }
                });
        });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo "successful"
?>
```

I have tried various available options on stackoverflow but none of them is working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOOGk.png)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
$('#submit').click(function()
```

**Still not working**
But when I am including the above script to code it is going in infinite loop and throwing error as "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
I have done three changes in my existing code.
1) Added script src 
I have also tried adding other similar scripts but all showing same error
that means there is some issue with code itself.
2)Added event to statement 
$('#submit').click(function(event) 
3)placed php in single quotes
url: 'insertdata.php'.

Comment: You haven't included jQuery (or any library with an `.ajax()` method which uses `$` as a shortcut). Furthermore the selector is wrong as there is no element with `id="submit"`

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include a reference to the jquery source

Answer (score 1):

**please do correction in code as**

```
1.) add script to below your form close - <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

2.) add id in submit button - <input type="submit" id="submit"  value="Skicka Tips" />
```

Comment: But when I am including the above script to code it is going in infinite loop and throwing error as "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
I have done three changes in my existing code.
1) Added <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I have also tried adding other similar scripts but all showing same error
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>-->

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery first to before starting your script. It is not loaded that's why `$` is not defined error came.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And You are not passing the event object here

```
$('#submit').click(function() {})
```

Add it in your code

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {});
```

Or remove the submit type from your input button as

```
<input type="button" value="Skicka Tips" />
```

Comment: @Andreas i updated my answer, i didn't see the last line

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no `event` passed in your

```
$('#submit').click(function(){})
```

You'd have to change that to

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {})
```

to work.

Secondly, your

```
<input type="submit"   value="Skicka Tips" />
```

has no `id` so jQuery cannot find it using the `#` identifier.

You either have to change that to

```
<input type="submit" id="submit"  value="Skicka Tips" />
```

or use the `onsubmit` event with the form.